# Where is code of the instantiation of C++ vector?

Tags: c++, stl

I have a very simple code as below, which uses a C++ vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
  
using namespace std;
  
int main()
{
    vector<int> g1;
  
    return 0;
}
```

By coping the code to the website https://godbolt.org/, I know the generated assembly code is as below:

```
main:
        stp     x29, x30, [sp, -64]!
        mov     x29, sp
        str     x19, [sp, 16]
        add     x0, sp, 40
        bl      std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::vector()** [complete object constructor]
        mov     w19, 0
        add     x0, sp, 40
        bl      std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::~vector() [complete object destructor]
        mov     w0, w19
        ldr     x19, [sp, 16]
        ldp     x29, x30, [sp], 64
        ret
__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int):
        stp     x29, x30, [sp, -32]!
        mov     x29, sp
        str     w0, [sp, 28]
        str     w1, [sp, 24]
        ldr     w0, [sp, 28]
        cmp     w0, 1
        bne     .L27
        ldr     w1, [sp, 24]
        mov     w0, 65535
        cmp     w1, w0
        bne     .L27
        adrp    x0, _ZStL8__ioinit
        add     x0, x0, :lo12:_ZStL8__ioinit
        bl      std::ios_base::Init::Init() [complete object constructor]
        adrp    x0, __dso_handle
        add     x2, x0, :lo12:__dso_handle
        adrp    x0, _ZStL8__ioinit
        add     x1, x0, :lo12:_ZStL8__ioinit
        adrp    x0, _ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
        add     x0, x0, :lo12:_ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev
        bl      __cxa_atexit
.L27:
        nop
        ldp     x29, x30, [sp], 32
        ret
_GLOBAL__sub_I_main:
        stp     x29, x30, [sp, -16]!
        mov     x29, sp
        mov     w1, 65535
        mov     w0, 1
        bl      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)
        ldp     x29, x30, [sp], 16
        ret
DW.ref.__gxx_personality_v0:
        .xword  __gxx_personality_v0
```

Now my question is where I can find the code of **std::vector<int, std::allocator >::vector()**.

If I define a new template class in my code as below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
  
template <class T, class U> class A {
    T x;
    U y;
  
public:
    A() { cout << "Constructor Called" << endl; }
};
  
int main()
{
    A<char, char> a;
    A<int, double> b;
    return 0;
}
```

I know the code of A<char, char> and A<int, double> is generated in the object file of my own code. But for the template class and template function of C++ STL, where is the code of their instantiated object?

There is in the library file of the C++ standard library, e.g. **libstdc++.so**, but I think the compiler will not generate the code inside that .so file.

Thanks!

Comment: The template for `std::vector` is in the `<vector>` header file.  The instantiations will be in the TUs where they are used.

Comment: Click on "Filter..." on godbolt.org and uncheck the box next to "Library functions"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are simply confused because godbolt.org doesn't show standard library functions by default in the assembly view.

Click on "Filter..." and then deselect "Library functions".

Then you will get the missing symbols, for example the `std::vector<int>` default constructor and destructor.

They are not shown by default because there is usually no interest in them and there can be many library functions cluttering the output.

In some instances the standard library uses explicit instantiation into the `.so` instead of implicit instantiation into the translation unit using the standard library template. Libstdc++ does this for `std::string` (which is `std::basic_string<char>`) if I remember correctly, but I don't think any standard library implementation does this for `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

> I know the code of A<char, char> and A<int, double> is generated in the object file of my own code. But for the template class and template function of C++ STL, where is the code of their instantiated object?

Exactly the same: they are templated types, and only your specific instantiation makes `std::vector<int, std::allocator >::vector()` exist.

You'll need to think about this in terms of *translation units*; so, this machine code will be found in each translation unit that includes the header and instantiates that specific type.

Comment: It should be noted that `#include <vector>` simply adds the contents of the vector file to the translation unit. It's the same as writing the `class A` in the file.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow heh, as you wrote that, I edited my question to mention the inclusion.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow A further question, if STL template use the libc function, e.g., allocator use new, new use malloc, is the code of libc function in the libc.so instead of in the translation unit of my code? Thanks!

Comment: @SimonZhu usually, yes, but you can link that in if you want to!